# Restricting the quotient map of rings to a subring

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, quotient-spaces

When $q$ maps $R$ to $R/I$ and $p$ is the restriction of $q$ to a subring $A$ of $R$, why is the image of $p$ $(A+I)/I$?

$q$ maps $r$ to $r+I$, so shouldn't $p$ map $a \in A$ to $a+I$, so image of $p$ is the set $\{a+I : a\in A\}?$

Comment: Your section line is correct, but it does not contradict your first.

Comment: Are you saying that $\{a+I\} = (A+I)/I$?

Comment: Tell me what $(A + I)/I$ is, set-theoretically. Just as you did for the image of the map $A \to R/I$.

Comment: $(A+I)/I=\{a+i+I:a\in A,i\in I\}.$ So this equals $\{a+I\}$?

Comment: I think you've basically got it. The point is that $a + i + I = a + I$ (this is just group theory). So one side is $\bigcup_{a \in A,\,i\in I} \{a + I\}$ and the other is $\bigcup_{a \in A} \{a + I\}$; the former has more indices in some sense but it doesn't matter, for the same reason that $\{1,1\} = \{1\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $p : A \rightarrow R/I$ given by $p = q\vert_A$. The first isomorphism theorem provides $A/\ker(p) \simeq p(A)$. It should be evident that $\ker(p) = I \cap A$, so $A/(I \cap A) \simeq p(A)$. The second isomorphism theorem provides $(A + I)/I \simeq A/(A \cap I)$, so $(A + I)/I \simeq p(A)$

Comment: I'm actually trying to prove the second isomorphism theorem by showing that $p(A)=I+A.$ Is there another way to show it? When I searched on the internet (for example, on ProofWiki), they don't give an explanation so I was thinking there would be a simpler explanation?

Comment: On WikiProof, the quotient $(S + J)/J$ expresses the cosets $s + J$ for $s \in S$. We can not say $S/J$ since it is not necessarily true that $J$ is an ideal of the subring $S$ (that is, a subset of $S$) .. rather, $S \cap J$ is an ideal of $S$.